# what can i do to check whether each element in a list matches a certain condition in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have a list like:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And I want to get the result like:

```
whether_greater_than_two = [False, False, True, True, True]
```

In R, I can easily apply `nums > 2` to get the above result. But what should I do in Python 2.7? If I use `nums > 2` again, I'll only get one `False`.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension, as others already showed. If you're really concerned about performance, use *numpy arrays* instead:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> na = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> na > 2
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

If you're coming from an R background, chances are you at least have *numpy* installed already with *matplotlib* (and possibly with a lot of other data analysis related packages) in Python

Answer (score 2):

You can build a list comprehension:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5]
over_two = [num > 2 for num in nums]
```

#### output:

```
[False, False, True, True, True]
```

Comment: oh yes!! I forget the list comprehension! Thanks!

Comment: this is not Python syntax

Comment: you have a `:` instead of an equal sign

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
whether_greater_than_two = [ i>2 for i in nums ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a few ways, the two most popular ones will probably be list comprehension and map:

#### list comprehension

```
whether_greater_than_two = [x > 2 for x in nums]
```

#### map

```
whether_greater_than_two = map(lambda x: x > 2, nums)
```

pay attention that in Python 3 map returns an object that you can iterate, but if you want a list you'll have to wrap it with a `list()` call:

```
list(map(lambda x: x > 2, nums))
```

And of course, you can do it with a good old...

#### for-loop

```
result = []
for x in nums:
    result.append(x > 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
map(lambda num: num > 2, nums)

[num > 2 for num in nums]
```

Also check `numpy` out, it provides shortcuts to these kind of calculation and does them faster than plain python.